Allow Product Authors to Purchase Private Product
I am managing a WordPress site with WooCommerce where, users can create products for their event and make them either public or private.
Unfortunately when they make product private, they are able to see the product when logged on but cannot purchase the ticket.
How can I allow allow authors to purchase their own private products?
add_action( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'purchasable_fix', 10, 2);
function purchasable_fix($is_purchasable, $object) {
    $statuses = array("publish", "private");
    return ($object->exists() && ( in_array($object->get_status(), $statuses) || current_user_can( 'edit_post', $object->get_id() ) ) && '' !== $object->get_price());
}

